# Return new JS object using previous object values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I have an object of objects (for example):

```
const previousMap = {123456: {title: 'Test 1', productID: 123456}, 234567: {title: 'Test 2', productID: 234567}}
```

and would like to return a new object, with each key as the titles of the previous object, and its values as the sku (which also happen to be the keys of the last object-- but I would rather use the .sku attribute).

For example:

```
const newMap = {'Test 1' : 123456, 'Test 2': 234567}
```

I have tried:

```
newMap = Object.entries(previousMap).map(([key, value]) => ({[value.title] : value.productID}))
```

but wind up getting an array of objects.

This is something that I feel as though I would normally be able to accomplish but my brain is really not working today. Any help = greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:
Changing the map to return an array of key and value `[k,v]` and then calling [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on it.

```js
const previousMap = {
  123456: {
    title: 'Test 1',
    productID: 123456
  },
  234567: {
    title: 'Test 2',
    productID: 234567
  }
}

let newMap = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(previousMap)
  .map(([key, value]) => [value.title, value.productID])
);

console.log(newMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `.map` will, by definition, always return an array.  Instead you can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), starting with an empty object as the initial value for your accumulator, and spread it into the new return object at each iteration:

```js
const previousMap = {
  123456: {
    title: 'Test 1',
    productID: 123456
  },
  234567: {
    title: 'Test 2',
    productID: 234567
  }
}

const newMap = Object.entries(previousMap)
  .reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [value.title]: value.productID
    }), {}
  );

console.log(newMap);
```

You could also just accomplish this with a plain loop and keep mutating a single object instead, if you desired.